# Can't get rid of '!' item on SVN

Tags: svn

I struggle to get rid of a '!' pdf file with SVN. I don't know how it got here. I try to svn del it, svn add it again but when I do so, I see it twice, on with 'A' and the other with '!'. It is still on my repository, that is why I also tried to checkout the folder, but even when I do see, the file come back but still with the '!' flag.

Any idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A file with the status of `!` is missing from the working copy or incomplete.

**Incomplete**

Incomplete files happen when Subversion is interrupted when doing an operation to install the file.  `svn cleanup` can be used to resolve this.  Usually other commands will prompt you if this is the case so I don't think that's your situation.

**Missing Files**

Missing files mean a file was removed from your working copy without using a Subversion command to do so.  You can recover from such situations by running `svn revert file`

If neither of these cases work you may be running into the following issue.

**Unicode Issues on OS X**

OS X normalizes unicode characters in file/directory names with HFS+.  Subversion is not really aware of this and so it will see the file as missing.  If this was happening you'd see the file twice (with apparently the same name though differing in the exact unicode characters output to reach the same display), one with `!` and one with `?` status.  I suspect this isn't your specific case since you don't mention seeing a `?` status, though it still could be if you were using the `-q` option with status.  [Subversion issue #2464](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2464) is about this and there's working being undertaken to resolve this.  There's also an unofficial patch which helps avoid the problem but doesn't solve the problem in a fully compatible way (and hasn't been applied to Subversion as a result).  The patch can be found on the linked issue.

Comment: Actually, the last case seems to be mine. I still had the `!` tag, even after the `revert`, so I tried to make an `update` and then I can see my file twice, one with the `!` and the other with the `?`. Thank you for your advice. I will check your link now.